# Find files with specific age in folder except in several subfolders

Tags: bash, find, ctime

I am looking for a possibility in linux bash to find files older then X days in a folder and all subfolders except some subfolders I exclude.

I have the following:
`find /Folder -ctime +30 -path './ExcludedSubfolder' -prune -o -name '*.*' -print`

But it doesn't work. It searches for the files except in the folder, but the -ctime +30 doesn't work.

Finally I want to delete all files older than 30 days in a folder and all subfolders except some subfolders I exclude.

It should like something like this:
`find /Folder -ctime +30 -path './ExcludedSubfolder' -prune -o -name '*.*' -exec rm {} \; > deleted.txt`

Thanks for any help!

System is on SLES 11 SP2.

Comment: Depends on what you want. `-ctime` is the time the `inode` wast last modified. `-mtime` (modification time), might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Solution wasn't that far...

`find . -ctime +1 -o \( -path ./tmp -o -path ./bla \) -prune -o -name '*.*' -exec rm {} \;`

Finally -o was missing... ctime or mtime did not matter in this case. Thanks anyway.